# R converting space separated data frame element to vector

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I'm reading off from a csv file `animals.csv` as such

```
type,kid,traits
dog,puppy,1 2 3 4 5
cat,kitten,6 7 8 9 10
```

After I read this whole file into a data frame using

`animals = read.csv('animals.csv', header=TRUE)`

The only problem is that for the column trait, each of the elements is a string. I need them to be vectors of integers eg. `c(1,2,3,4,5)` `c(6,7,8,9,10)`.

I've tried searching for ways to do this easily and I can't seem to find any.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `strsplit`.

```
> animals$traits <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(animals$traits), " "), as.numeric)
> animals
  type    kid         traits
1  dog  puppy  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2  cat kitten 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
> str(animals)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ type  : Factor w/ 2 levels "cat","dog": 2 1
 $ kid   : Factor w/ 2 levels "kitten","puppy": 2 1
 $ traits:List of 2
  ..$ : num  1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ : num  6 7 8 9 10
```

This is likely to be a somewhat messy structure to work with though.

Instead, I would suggest looking at `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, which would give you the data you need in a more easily usable format:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(animals, "traits", " ")  ## Start with the original dataset
#    type    kid traits_1 traits_2 traits_3 traits_4 traits_5
# 1:  dog  puppy        1        2        3        4        5
# 2:  cat kitten        6        7        8        9       10
cSplit(animals, "traits", " ", direction = "long")
#     type    kid traits
#  1:  dog  puppy      1
#  2:  dog  puppy      2
#  3:  dog  puppy      3
#  4:  dog  puppy      4
#  5:  dog  puppy      5
#  6:  cat kitten      6
#  7:  cat kitten      7
#  8:  cat kitten      8
#  9:  cat kitten      9
# 10:  cat kitten     10
str(.Last.value)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ type  : Factor w/ 2 levels "cat","dog": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
#  $ kid   : Factor w/ 2 levels "kitten","puppy": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
#  $ traits: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the traits data for each row isn't always the same length. Basically traits represents a sparse vector for clustering work later on.

Thanks so much let me try this out now!

Comment: @Linan, that shouldn't be a problem for `cSplit`, in either the wide or the long form. `cSplit` does expect that the other columns are unique though, so if the third row were, say, "cat,kitten,1 2, 3", you would have to modify the source to have a unique row-wise ID.

Comment: So I tried this out and now each element is a list

```
[[9998]]
[1] 1

[[9999]]
[1] 2 1 1 1

[[10000]]
[1] 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Instead, is it possible to have each element as simply the vector, and not a one element list?

Comment: @Linan, yes. That's what I showed in the `str` output for the first option. What do you want? An actual character representation of the string `"c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"`?

Comment: is it possible for each element to be a vector? For example, in order to access the elements in traits, right now I have to do animals$traits[5][[1]][5] Instead I'd want animals$traits[5][5] and not make each item a list in itself

Comment: @Linan, You shouldn't have nested lists. You should be able to do something like `animals$traits[[1]][3]` (which would return "3" with this sample data) or `animals$traits[[2]][3]` (which would return "8" with this sample data). In other words, `[[` to indicate the row number and `[` to indicate the position in the vector.